# How to combine existing async requests with RxAndroid or using Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, rx-android, kotlin-coroutines

Here is my code. I have async request which is implemented in SDK .
I am using it, I have implemented it simple way calling login providing callback for that async request.
My question is it possible if to combine this Async request using RxAndroid or Kotlin Coroutines?
As I am going to have a lot of callback chains to avoid it I am thinking to combine with RxJava or Kotlin Coroutines.
Any hints of referening to a sample could be goodl

````
private fun automaticLogin() {
    UserAction(username, password).login(AutomaticUserLoginRequest(this))
}


class AutomaticUserLoginRequest()
    : UserLoginRequest( object : ILoginResultHandler {
    override fun onSuccess(session: ISession) {
    }

    override fun onError(error: Error) {
    }
  })```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do something like with the `suspendCoroutine` function:

```
suspend fun automaticUserLoginRequest(): ISession {
  return suspendCoroutine<ISession> { cont ->
    callUserLoginRequest(object : ILoginResultHandler {
      override fun onSuccess(session: ISession) {
         cont.resume(session)
      }

      override fun onError(error: Error) {
         cont.resumeWithException(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may execute the suspend function from a coroutine. The kotlinx.coroutines-android provides the `Dispatchers.UI` for that:

```
fun someFunction() {
   //starts a coroutine, not waiting fro result
   launch(Dispatchers.UI) {

     val session = automaticUserLoginRequest()

     //the execution will resume here once login is done, it can be an exception too
     updateUI(session)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-android/README.md

Comment: How this is working under the hood ?
and I see a lot of tutorials how to use coroutines but how they are working under the hood, I don't get how they are providing asynchronous.

Comment: Coroutines under the hood are implemented as state machines. Every suspension point is a state. Resumes are implemented as callbacks. So coroutines are essentially the way to turn callbacks into an ordinary code